# Excel Subtract 2 Cells if Cell Equals a specific value

Tags: excel

at work we are trying to create a simple inventory tracker in excel.
The one thing we can not figure out is how to get the tracker to subtract a value

Ex. We have whats in storage Column G is the object and Column H is how much. In Column A you put what your taking and then in Column D you put how much your taking. We want D to subtract from H if A = G.
[image]
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a new column for this, if you don't want to use VBA programming.

=H4-SUMIF($A$4:$A$11;G4;$D$4:$D$11)

if you want to fill up your storage again, you can either write a minus in the outtake column or use a different column for "fill up items"
then you use this formula:

=H15-SUMIF($A$4:$A$11;G15;$D$4:$D$11)+SUMIF($A$4:$A$11;G15;$C$4:$C$11)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I kind of understand where your going with it put got a little lost trying to implement it. I have attached a snip it to my original post so you can see what im working with.